# Проверка принтера

Tags: print, java

Как проверить, включен ли принтер в данный момент?

**Обновление**

Я имею в виду программно, в джава. Например, я написал метод для печати документа, и мне нужно проверить, активен ли принтер, если нет - сообщить об этом пользователю.

Comment: посмотреть на индикатор питания

Comment: Я имею ввиду программно, в джава. Например, я написал метод для печати документа, и мне нужно проверить, активен ли принтер, если нет- сообщить об этом пользователю

Comment: @Putnik13, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Покажите код, который вы написали?

Comment: @Putnik13, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Вот код. Лазил по форумам, все, что нашел, не работает http://pastebin.com/d9E6wRaY

Answer (score 1):

Java использует системное АПИ для печати документов. При печати появляется системное окно, где пользователь может выбрать принтер. И о том, что данный конкретный принтер выключен, пользователю сообщит система, и вашему ПО об этом заботиться нет необходимости.

Comment: Не сообщает. http://pastebin.com/d9E6wRaY